# How to determine which files are been used to configure my correct shell session?

Tags: shell, bash

Let's say you have bash-profile, bashrc and maybe zshrc dot files in your system.

How to determine which file is responsible for example Python PATH$ variable?

I am currently uninstalling conda from my system and system stubbornly claims Python path to be

```
➜  ~ which python
/anaconda/bin/python
```

I have already concluded that my `bashrc`, `bash-profile` or `zshrc` files have no pointer to this location. Is there a command that allows me to see where my system is pointed to specific PATH variable or even what files are active in configuring current shell session?

Comment: The command "env" will show all you environment variables and so "env | grep PATH" will show the path to your executable. You can modify your PATH environmental variable with the export command.

Comment: Which shell do you use? The bash files and the zsh files are mutually exclusive unless a file from one set explicitly sources a file from the other. Knowing which shell will also let you know which file to add `set -x` to, which will provide you with a full trace of commands executed when the shell starts. That will lead you to where `/anaconda/bin` is added to your path.

Comment: I use zsh. Btw. I figured where it was added. it was actually in my zshrc file it s just that I cltr + f the file for the word python when in fact it was added with export PATH="/anaconda/bin:$PATH" to path...